# How to get reference to dom elements for a range of rows in ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

So far I have found `getLine()` and `getAllLines()` methods, but they return the string contents of the specified lines.

```
let line = this.editor.session.getLine(30);
let lines = this.editor.session.doc.getAllLines()
```

How can I request the dom element for a certain line? I want to highlight a set of lines but I want to avoid creating `selectionRange` because I want the selection range to be free for other stuff.

```
selectionRange = editor.getSelectionRange();

startLine = selectionRange.start.row;
endLine = selectionRange.end.row;

content = editor.session.getTextRange(selectionRange);
```

I would apply a css class changing the background color. Unfortunately there is no id class for `<div class="ace_line_group"` that I could highjack for this purpose. Also I would like to avoid any messy regex that loops all lines until it finds the ones I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... luckily, after some more googling I found the answer. It is also playing nice with webpack.

```
    var ace = require('brace');
    var Range = ace.acequire('ace/range').Range;
    editor.session.addMarker(
        new Range(1, 0, 15, 0), "ace_active-line", "fullLine", true
    );
```

However I still need a way to get that dom reference in order to float a tooltip over that region.